# how to concatenate two variables in batch

Tags: batch-file

Here I have generated two log files

### alertloglocation.log

> d:\app2\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace

### dbname.log

> orcl

### my Code

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (alertloglocation.log) do set alertlogloc=%%A

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (dbname.log) do set dbnm=%%A

echo %alertlogloc% \alert_%dbnm%.log >output.log
```

### output.log

> d:\app2\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace

Now I have two variables alertlogloc and dbname.

### Actually I want the output as:

> d:\app2\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\alert_orcl.log

Comment: Firstly - you might want to remove the space between `%alertlogloc%` and the filename - `echo %alertlogloc% \alert_%dbnm%.log >output.log`

Comment: What is the content of input files and what should be the content of output file? Also their all locations?

Answer (score 0):

The files and code in your question cannot give the result you are claiming. It produces `d:\app2\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace \alert_orcl.log`, with a trailing space.

Remove the space after `%alertlogloc%` as unclemeat suggests, and all should be fine. If you also want to remove the trailing space, then remove the space before the redirection. There is no need for `tokens=*` when you have `delims=`. I like to use quotes in my SET assignments to make sure I have no unwanted trailing spaces.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (alertloglocation.log) do set "alertlogloc=%%A"

for /f "delims=" %%A in (dbname.log) do set "dbnm=%%A"

echo %alertlogloc%\alert_%dbnm%.log>output.log
```

As long as you know that each file has only one line, then you can simplify:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (alertloglocation.log) do for /f "delims=" %%B in (dbname.log) do echo %%A\alert_%%B.log>output.log
```